# Opera jQuery load causes load of whole page

Tags: jquery, opera

Here is the part of my page with the problem.

```
<div id="notice_box" class="center">
  <div id="notice_cont"></div>
<script>
    function notice(more)
    {
        $('#notice_cont').load('notice.php?more_notice='+more);
    }
</script>
</div>
    <div id="notice_box_foot">
       <img src="images/notice-box-bl.png" class="left">
       <img src="images/notice-box-br.png" class="right">
     </div>
</div>
```

The script is supposed to fill #notice_cont with notice.php..... rather it fills the whole page with it.... works fine in all browsers except opera :s

Comment: Where does it get called from?

Comment: What are you're script doing up there?

Comment: And what is returned by notice.php? maybe returned container has height attribute = 100%. try to limit max_height of  notice_cont div

Comment: Are you sure the DOM is built when function is called? And when is it called?

Comment: It gets called like this <a style="margin-right:5px;" class="right" href="javascript:notice(3);"><img src="images/not-less.png" /></a>

Comment: The div does not have 100% height :) @MattTheCat Yes because it is on the click of the link and it happens when clicking it after the page is fully loaded

Comment: Yes, this may be a duplicate, but none of the answers to either question actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because your script tag is inside the div. Try moving it to after the .

Answer (score 0):

Please try to validate the output of notice.php with the [W3C HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org). The symptoms you describe might happen if the HTML you insert is not valid, e.g. with missing end tags.